# Remove item from array using splice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue JS, I have 2 different arrays `categories` and `items`. Each item can belong to multiple categories, the items are generated dynamically and therefore not initially associated in the category array. Then I parse the category array to create tables containing the different items.

For testing purposes, I attach the items to it's associated category in the mounted vue property, as follows:

```
mounted: function() {
  for (let item of this.items) {
    for (let category of item.categories) {
      this.categories[category - 1].items.push(item)
    }
  }
}
```

Then when the delete button is pressed, I trigger a `deleteItem` method which uses splice to delete the item from the `categories` array and from the `items` array as well, but I am having a little issue there that the correct item does not get deleted.

```
  methods: {
    deleteItem: function(item) {
      for (let category of item.categories) {
        this.categories[category - 1].items.splice(this.categories[category - 1].items.indexOf(item, 1))
      }
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item, 1))
    }
  }
```

Please see the example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enriqg9/en6d7c44/). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item, 1))
```

to

```
this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1)
```

so that you pass `1` as second argument to `splice`.

Note that you do the same error twice.

Comment: Thank you! didn't catch that